# Vectorize actions over a 'groupby' instead of for-loops to make the code run faster?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Relatively new to working with pandas, dataframes etc.

I'm trying to make our code that has hundreds of millions of rows (when completely expanded) work faster and more efficiently. I am using `.groupby()` on a specific column to get a few hundred thousand groups, and then I want to perform some simple math + column addition actions on each as presented below. This gives me lists of data with an item for each group.

Until this point I managed to get everything to work relatively fast, but at this point this definition takes an excessively long time. I keep hearing about vectorization instead of for looping, but I can't find a direct example that helps me solve how to change my definition to be based on vectorization.

this is the def:

```
def add_data_df(df1,df2):
  df1_group = df1.copy().groupby('ORG_INDEX', sort=False)
  sums=[]
  min_gfa=[]
  max_gfa=[]
  min_uni=[]
  max_uni=[]
  for group in df1_group:
    groupdf = group[1]
    sum_a = np.sum(groupdf['F_AREA'])
    sums.append(sum_a)

    groupdf['MINGFA'] = (groupdf['MIN_FLR'] * groupdf['F_AREA']) + (groupdf['MIN_FLR2'] * groupdf['F_AREA2'])
    groupdf['MAXGFA'] = (groupdf['MAX_FLR'] * groupdf['F_AREA']) + (groupdf['MAX_FLR2'] * groupdf['F_AREA2'])
    groupdf['MINUNITS'] = (groupdf['MIN_FLR'] * groupdf['UNITS_F']) + (groupdf['MIN_FLR2'] * groupdf['UNITS_F2'])
    groupdf['MAXUNITS'] = (groupdf['MAX_FLR'] * groupdf['UNITS_F']) + (groupdf['MAX_FLR2'] * groupdf['UNITS_F2'])

    min_gfa.append(np.sum(groupdf['MINGFA']))
    max_gfa.append(np.sum(groupdf['MAXGFA']))
    min_uni.append(np.sum(groupdf['MINUNITS']))
    max_uni.append(np.sum(groupdf['MAXUNITS']))

  df2['SUM_AREA']=sums
  df2['MIN_GFA']=min_gfa
  df2['MAX_GFA']=max_gfa
  df2['MIN_UNITS']=min_uni
  df2['MAX_UNITS']=max_uni
```

Thank you!
Lev

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
df2 = df.copy()
df2['MINGFA'] = (df2['MIN_FLR'] * df2['F_AREA']) + (df2['MIN_FLR2'] * df2['F_AREA2'])
df2['MAXGFA'] = (df2['MAX_FLR'] * df2['F_AREA']) + (df2['MAX_FLR2'] * df2['F_AREA2'])
df2['MINUNITS'] = (df2['MIN_FLR'] * df2['UNITS_F']) + (df2['MIN_FLR2'] * df2['UNITS_F2'])
df2['MAXUNITS'] = (df2['MAX_FLR'] * df2['UNITS_F']) + (df2['MAX_FLR2'] * df2['UNITS_F2'])

df2 \
    .groupby('ORG_INDEX', as_index=False, sort=False) \
    .sum() \
    [['ORG_INDEX', 'F_AREA', 'MINGFA', 'MAXGFA', 'MINUNITS', 'MAXUNITS']] \
    .rename({'F_AREA': 'SUMS'}, axis=1)
```

Explanation:

1. The calculations below from your code are performed for each group, but they are just element-wise multiplications and sums. That means that you can perform those for the whole dataframe just once and nothing will change.

```
groupdf['MINGFA'] = (groupdf['MIN_FLR'] * groupdf['F_AREA']) + (groupdf['MIN_FLR2'] * groupdf['F_AREA2'])
groupdf['MAXGFA'] = (groupdf['MAX_FLR'] * groupdf['F_AREA']) + (groupdf['MAX_FLR2'] * groupdf['F_AREA2'])
groupdf['MINUNITS'] = (groupdf['MIN_FLR'] * groupdf['UNITS_F']) + (groupdf['MIN_FLR2'] * groupdf['UNITS_F2'])
groupdf['MAXUNITS'] = (groupdf['MAX_FLR'] * groupdf['UNITS_F']) + (groupdf['MAX_FLR2'] * groupdf['UNITS_F2'])
```

2. All the other calculations are the sums of all the values in each group. This can be achived by grouping the dataframe and performing sum for each group.
3. Filtering and renaming the columns if needed.

P.S. I am copying the initial dataframe in the first row because it seemed like you needed a new one as a result. But you can also perform all the calculations on the initial dataframe to avoid copying.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. Unfortunately this solution absolutely destroys my memory, resulting in a crash (working in Google Colab with 50GB of memory). The method with the for loop takes a very long time, but it seems to not affect the memory in this way...

Comment: Does the same happen if you perform the calculations on the original dataframe?

Comment: It does. I'm looking for ways to incorporate Parquet to slice the data into smaller groups and perform these actions on each. Any other ideas are very welcome!